# Difference between "Don't usually", "Usually Don't"

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

I wonder whats different between two.

> We **do not usually** do our work.
>
> We **usually do not** do our work

Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first carries an implication that someone else might do it instead.  The second doesn't.  eg

> "We **don't usually** do our taxes - we hire an accountant to do it".
>
> "We **usually don't** do the taxes.  It's amazing that we haven't been imprisoned yet."

Comment: I don't think it is as simple as that. It could depend on what comes before or after, the nature of the remark we are making etc. This is idiomatic fine-tuning of some detail.  "We don't usually do our work on Fridays" sounds ok. So does "If the boss insults us, we usually (in protest) don't do our work" also sounds ok.

Comment: Can you explain it more?

Answer (score 5):

Both sentences are very similar, and mean almost the same thing. In spoken language, you could use them interchangeably and any native speaker would understand you just fine. However, they do have some subtle differences that give the sentences a bit of a different meaning. If you're focusing on written English, it may be important to keep these in mind as it would give a different flavor to your writing.

These kinds of questions are very common (I think this is the third one I've answered on this very forum). The difference is difficult to explain in plain English because it's just something that you kind of *feel* as a speaker. In my opinion, the best way to look at these questions is to view them from an *analytical* perspective. By breaking it down and putting the pieces back together, we can better understand the underlying meaning of why these sentences are different.

In the first sentence, the root is **we usually do work** (I'm removing *our* here because it's not relevant from a grammatical perspective). This means that the work is usually done. *Do not* (or *don't*) is an adjective phrase which modifies *usually* by inverting its meaning. So instead of meaning that the work is almost always done, it means that the work is seldom done.

In the second sentence, the root is **we do not do work**. *Usually* is an adjective that modifies *do not*, meaning that most of the time, the work is not done.

Looking at it from this perspective, try to see if you can understand what's going on here and why the sentences are different. Good luck!